Integrating acceleration data to obtain the trajectory - where did I do mistake?
I am trying to implement the code to obtain UAV flight trajectory by double integrating its acceleration data.
To start with I prepared a dummy flight trajectory and double differentiated it to get the corresponding acceleration data:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
num_samples = 1000
dt = 0.01  # time step

# Generate time array
t = np.linspace(0, num_samples * dt, num_samples)

# Define a simple trajectory (e.g., a spiral)
x = np.sin(t)
y = np.cos(t)
z = t / 10

# Compute velocities
v_x = np.gradient(x, dt)
v_y = np.gradient(y, dt)
v_z = np.gradient(z, dt)

# Compute accelerations
a_x = np.gradient(v_x, dt)
a_y = np.gradient(v_y, dt)
a_z = np.gradient(v_z, dt)

# Add some noise to the accelerations (more on this at the end of the post)
# noise_std = 0.1
# a_x += np.random.normal(0, noise_std, num_samples)
# a_y += np.random.normal(0, noise_std, num_samples)
# a_z += np.random.normal(0, noise_std, num_samples)

# Combine data into arrays
accelerometer_data = np.vstack((a_x, a_y, a_z)).T

# Plot the synthetic data for visualization
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, a_x, label='a_x')
plt.plot(t, a_y, label='a_y')
plt.plot(t, a_z, label='a_z')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Accelerometer Data')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t, x, label='x')
plt.plot(t, y, label='y')
plt.plot(t, z, label='z')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Ground Truth Position')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

The output of the above code in jupyter notebook is a follows:

The trajectory can be visualised as follows:
# Plot the synthetic trajectory in 3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot(x, y, z, label='Ground Truth Trajectory')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.legend()
plt.title('3D Ground Truth Trajectory')
plt.show()


Nect, I tried to integrate the acceleration data twice to obtain back the trajectory:
position = np.zeros((num_samples, 3))
velocity = np.zeros((num_samples, 3))

# Numerical integration to compute trajectory
for i in range(1, num_samples):
    # Update velocity
    velocity[i] = velocity[i-1] + accelerometer_data[i] * dt
    # Update position
    position[i] = position[i-1] + velocity[i] * dt

# Plot the synthetic trajectory in 3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot(x, y, z, label='Ground Truth Trajectory')
ax.plot(position[:, 0], position[:, 1], position[:, 2], label='Estimated Trajectory')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.legend()
plt.title('3D Trajectory')
plt.show()

This outputs:

As we can notice, the estimated trajectory does not match with the ground truth trajectory. This is even when no noise is added to the acceleration data. Even when the noise is added to the acceleration data (uncomment the corresponding lines in the first code snippet), we still get the same estimated trajectory that does not align with the actual trajectory. I thought, I should get the same original trajectory when no noise is added to the acceleration data, as its just undoing the double differentiation with double integration. But it seems that either my concepts are messed up or am mathematically dumb or am simply doing something stupid. What is that?

When you differentiate, you lose information about constants, hence, when you integrate, you need to find the value of the constant of integration by using additional information. In your case, this translates to the acceleration data not containing information about the initial condition, i.e., the initial position and velocity. Without this additional information, you can experience a affine drift away from the expected answer when you integrate twice (affine drift due to the two constants of integration).

Ohkay I can understand about the position. But what if the initial velocity is zero? That is what if the IMU was steady before data capturing starts? In that case, it should just result in translated trajectory with the same shape, right?

Yeah, that's correct. Your example trajectory does not have zero initial velocity though.

ohkay one dumb question ... how you could tell by looking at say plot or code I shared that my initial velocity was NOT zero?

The slope of both x and z at t=0 are non-zero.
If you look at the trajectory for z, this has no acceleration, but it's not standing still either. Without telling the integration what the initial slope is, there is no hope to figure this out from all zero acceleration measurements.
